# call python def function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

i  run a python script in nodejs . it works . But I want to stay open and then call the def function from nodejs several times. how can i do that.

nodejs

```
let {PythonShell}=require( 'python-shell');


let py=PythonShell.run('test.py', null, function (err, results) {

  console.log('results: %j', results);
});
```

test.py

```
print('start');

def hello():
    print ('hello');
```

Comment: You can run your nodejs code multiple times. Just put it inside a function and then call it

Answer (score 0):

Calling a specific function at runtime is not a supported functionality of the `PythonShell` library without configuring the target Python script to do so. For example, consider the following Python script file based on your current example:

```
print('start')

def hello():
    print ('hello')

if "say-hello" in sys.argv:
    hello()
```

You can pass the `say-hello` argument when invoking your script file from Node to execute this method as you seem to want to do:

```
let {PythonShell}=require( 'python-shell');


let py=PythonShell.run('test.py', ["say-hello"], function (err, results) {
  console.log('results: %j', results);
});
```

Comment: no. for example i want to load a db in first of python . then i want to run query several time with different parameter . if i run your code every time i call python shell i should be wait to load db.

Comment: This type of functionality is not supported in your library of choice. Why not just do it directly in Node at that rate??

Comment: because database is binary and methods is very huge .i cant covert all of them to nodejs . do u have any better solution

Answer (score -1):

If im not mistaken, you want to run the python script seveal times?

put the `let py=pythonShell...` in a function and call that as many times as you want